# Can I Validate Two Fields Instead of One Field With This JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I use the javascript below to validate the Phone Number field on my form by showing the next hidden field whenever the value the user inputs in the phone number field on my form matches with the values in my javascript.

however, if their input does not match with the values in my javascript, the hidden field remains hidden and the user will be unable to submit the form.

The javascript works fine for the phone field but I am trying to validate two different fields to match with the values in my javascript.

**For example,** I want to make the values users input on the phone field and the email field of my form match with the values in my javascript before the hidden field shows.

**Illustration below;**

Lets say, the values in my javascript are; if (phone === "12345" && email === "12345@gmail.com")

**If the user inputs** Phone: 12345 and their email: 12345@gmail.com, **the hidden field shows**.

**If the user inputs** Phone:123 and their email: 12345@gmail.com, **the hidden field remains hidden**.

I have tried different solutions to validate the phone and email field but all my solutions failed and I need some help with this.

Sorry if my solution below is poor but I am not the owner of the original code.

Thanks for your help.

**Below is my sample code for the phone field validation. (WORKING FINE!)**

```js
$('.validate').hide();
$('body').on('blur', '#phone', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (isPhoneInUse(value)) {
    $(".validate").show();
  } else {
  alert ("Phone do not match!\nYou cannot submit this form!");
    $(".validate").hide();
  }
});
$('#submitForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  var value = $("#phone").val();
  if (isPhoneInUse(value)) {
    // validation failed. cancel the event
    console.log("not submitting");
    return false;
  }
})

function isPhoneInUse(phone) {
  return (phone === "1234" || phone === "23456")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<form action='' method='POST' id="submitForm">
<div class="validate"><span style="color: red;"><b>Phone Matches!</b></span></div>

  <input type="phone" name='phone' required='' id="phone" placeholder="0000-000-0000" />

  <br/><br/>
<div class="validate">
  <button href='/' type='submit' id="submitForm">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**Below is my solution to validate the phone and email fields. (NOT WORKING!)**

```js
$('.validate').hide();
$('body').on('blur', '#phone', '#email', function() {
var value = $(this).val();
  if (isDataInUse( $("#phone").val(), $("#email").val() )) {
    $(".validate").show();
  } else {
  alert ("Phone and Email do not match!\nYou cannot submit this form!");
    $(".validate").hide();
  }
});
$('#submitForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  var value = $("#phone" && "#email".val());
  if (isDataInUse( $("#phone").val(), $("#email").val() )) {
    // validation failed. cancel the event
    console.log("not submitting");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})

function isDataInUse(phone, email) { 
return (phone === "1234" && email === "1234@gmail.com") 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<form action='' method='POST' id="submitForm">
<div class="validate"><span style="color: red;"><b>Phone and Email Matches!</b></span></div>

  <input type="phone" name='phone' required='' id="phone" placeholder="0000-000-0000" />
  <br/><br/>
    <input type="email" name='email' required='' id="email" placeholder="hello@youremail.com" />

  <br/><br/>
<div class="validate">
  <button href='/' type='submit' id="submitForm">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis here: `if (isPhoneInUse && (isEmailInUse(value)) {` it should be `if (isPhoneInUse && (isEmailInUse(value))) {` twice in your code

Comment: another here: `var value = $("#phone" && "email".val();` should be `var value = $("#phone" && "email".val());`

Comment: this `function isPhoneInUse(phone) && isEmailInUse(phone) {` doesn't make any sense

Comment: also please note, `<form>` and `<button>` have the same ID = `submitForm`. IDs should be unique.

Comment: Do you advice that I remove
function isPhoneInUse(phone) && isEmailInUse(phone) {
and will it work if removed?

Comment: that's not how you declare a function. You could declare it like `function isDataInUse(phone, email) { return (phone === "1234" && email === "1234@gmail.com") }`

Comment: and you call it like this `if (isDataInUse( $("#phone").val(), $("#email").val() )) { ....... }`

Comment: I have made the necessary corrections as you advised, please see the corrections above. Did I get them right?

Comment: you seem to have detached the html portion of your snippet from the js part. anyway, I did post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many corrections, here is a working snippet:

```js
$('.validate').hide();

$('#phone, #email').on('change', function() {
  let phone = $('#phone').val();
  let email = $('#email').val();
  if (isDataInUse(phone, email)) {
    $(".validate").show();
  } else {
  alert ("Phone or Email do not match!\nYou cannot submit this form!");
    $(".validate").hide();
  }
});

$('#theForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  let phone = $('#phone').val();
  let email = $('#email').val();
  if (isDataInUse(phone, email)) {
    // validation failed. cancel the event
    console.log("not submitting");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
})

function isDataInUse(phone, email) {
  return (phone === "1234" && email === "1234@gmail.com")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<form action='' method='POST' id="theForm">
<div class="validate"><span style="color: red;"><b>Phone and Email Matches!</b></span></div>

  <input type="phone" name='phone' required='' id="phone" placeholder="0000-000-0000" />
  <br/><br/>
    <input type="email" name='email' required='' id="email" placeholder="hello@youremail.com" />

  <br/><br/>
<div class="validate">
  <button href='/' type='submit' id="submitForm">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```